# How to find if an excel file has a multiple sheets or not using SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am having three excel files.

1. Sales.xlsx
2. Product.xlsx
3. Payment.xlsx

In Sales and Product file we are having only one sheet But in Payment file we have three sheets.

I am having two questions here.

1. How to know which file has multiple sheet using SAS code
2. I need to import all the sheets using macro.

Thanks in advance

I am reading all the file names using dread function and using proc sql into statement to import the data dynamically. But i dont know how to import if only one file has multiple sheets

Answer (score 3):

Use the libname engine and proc copy, by default, all datasets/worksheets will be copied over.

```
libname sales xlsx '...sales.xlsx';
libname payment xlsx '....payment.xlsx';

proc copy in=sales out=work;
run;

proc copy in=payment out=work;
run;

libname sales;
libname payment;
```

Comment: In this method I have to provide the file name. I don’t want to give the file name manually. I am looking for a method where sas itself fetch it

Comment: The way your question is phrased, the method seems irrelevant if you're creating macro variables (proc sql into). Please show your code and I'll see how this can fit in.